# Does PayPal allow urls with subdomain - dev?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, return, paypal-ipn

i am using `dev.sample.com` as return url. But it is not returning.

Form tag - `<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">`

The form fields -

```
<div class="paypal-form">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mysandbox@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://dev.sample.com/paypal_ipn/process">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sample Master">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100"><input type="hidden" name="encrypt" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://dev.sample.com/paypal_ipn/process">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="paynow"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
</div>
```

any help?

Comment: Can you also include form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable auto return url in you paypal account .otherwise it will ignore return fields

Comment: it is not validating the url.